# How to implement `scroll-spy` in such a way that multiple targets can be active at once?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy, affix

I've been playing around with Bootstrap a lot lately and I'm currently in the process of creating a new template for my website. I've done a lot of searching on this issue, but most of the things I find are for people that can't get `scrollspy` to work at all.

What I'd like to do is create a side-navigation that has a separate target for each letter of the alphabet. You click on a link to bring you to that section of the content panel. The content panel will be an alphabetized list of whatever. Manually scrolling the page should automatically set the links in the navbar to `active`, causing the letters to highlight (or whatever I decide to do with them via CSS).

For those of you who are familiar with the iPhone, it is much like what they have implemented when viewing organized lists such as the `Contacts` app. Let's say that the viewport shows several alphabetized names, starting from `D` at the top of the viewport, and `H` at the bottom.

With `scrollspy`, only the closest target is being highlighted. The example below shows what I mean.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/ExWDq/embedded/result/

I hope that I've been specific enough for you to understand what I am trying to do. Let me know if I've lost you anywhere and I'll try and re-explain a bit better.

Is `scrollspy` the tool to use to accomplish this task?

If I knew of a way to check if an element is visible on screen, I might be able to utilize that to make something in Javascript that could accomplish everything I need, but I was hoping to be able to use `scrollspy` for this.

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with scrollspy, but the functionality you're after isn't that complex:

Adapting the function provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) this should give you a list of which elements in a set are currently visible.  You can apply/remove whatever CSS classes you want given this information.

You can run this handler on the 'scroll' event in the browser, though you might want to '[throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)' or '[debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)' it.  I believe there are jQuery plugins that provide the equivalent, but each of those is only a dozen lines of code or so.

```
function getVisible( $els ) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    return $els.filter(function(i, elem) {
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        // Fully or partially visible, pick one

        // element is _fully_ visible
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));

        // element is _partially_ visible
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) || (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    });
}
```

Comment: This will work perfectly! I suppose I will have to add a class to each of my sections corresponding to the letters of the alphabet, and then loop through them with a jQuery.each() function, calling getVisible() for each item. This is a good enough solution for me, but if anyone knows of a way that Bootstrap can do this, I would be interested in how that's done as well. Thank you very much. ++

Comment: Actually the intent of this function is that you issue a query for _all_ of your sections and pass the result into this function.  It will return the list of sections that are visible.  You could tag each section with a `data-sectionName` attribute to map it back to the navigation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I hadn't paid much thought to the whole `$els.filter()` part, but now I see what it's doing. This is much more efficient than I thought, then. :)